# declaring a 2d array of pointers that point to different strings (in a 2d array)

Tags: c++

I actually need to sort a lot of words according to their lengths. So the words get stored in a 2d array. Now rather than having words itself in the sorted form I want to have a pointer to each word which can be stored in a 2d array where rows represent length of word -1 and columns  no. of words -1.

so words are in dictionary[a][b] and i want a  *sorted_list[max word size ][max no. of words]

i need help to pass on a single row of the *sorted_list to a function & access the words in that row.

EDIT:my attempt : this gives unhandled error at run time

```
    char *sublist[10][100];
    sublist[(strlen(d[j]))-1][count[(strlen(d[j]))-1]]= d+(j*10); count[strlen(d[j])-1]++;
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  If `sorted_list` is a 2D array of pointers, why is one of its dimensions "max word size"?

Comment: word length has a range of 1-10 and there are 100 words in the dictionary assuming worst case where all are of same length i'll need 100 pointers in a row and row[0] has words of length 1 row[2] has words of length 3 etc.

Comment: I still don't understand.  Please add some example code to your question, that demonstrates an example setup.

Comment: http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=1145485#s=p1

i am solving this problem and i want to sort dictionary into sub-lists w/o forming newer lists for each word lenght

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make a `std::multimap<std::string, LenghtComparator>`, where `LengthComparator` is a predicate that returns `s1.length() < s2.length()`? Then you can retrieve an `equal_range` of all words of a given length.

Comment: I think you meant `s1.length()`

Comment: @Kerrek SB thanks a lot for the suggestion.. this seems to be a much more hassle free approach...though i had to spend time understanding this ..new to programming :P. one point i need to know does the multimap sort my data? i need the order to be preserved. any suggestions?

Comment: @Aseem: Yes, multimaps (and maps and sets and multisets) keep their data ordered! That means your objects must be comparable. By providing a custom comparator, you can specify how objects are ordered. If you had used a `map` rather than a `multimap`, you could only have _one_ string for each length. By using a `multimap`, you can keep many.

Comment: so if i need the order in which the words were input i need to have a copy of the data in a multimap else i'll lose that order?

Comment: @Aseem: Yeah, maps are _not_ sequence containers. If you need to keep multiple orderings at once (e.g. the input order, fully sorted (length + alphabetic) and length-only partially sorted), maybe check out [Boost.multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not setup a hash-table using the word-size as the key-value, and then store the pointers to each `char` string in its associated hash-slot?  If you wanted, it could be done using either `std::unordered_map`, or you could make a hash-table yourself using a combination of `std::vector` and `std::list` with `strlen()` as your hashing function.  For instance, using the latter setup you could do something like the following:

```
char* my_string = "Something";

//create a hash-table with ten slots (that's what you have in your example)
//where each slot holds a word of N length
std::vector<std::list<char*> > hash_table(10);

//this will store my_string at the back of the list at hash_table[9]
hash_table[strlen(my_string)].push_back(my_string);

//if you want the current num elements in the list, that's easy to-do as well
int list_size = hash_table[9].size();
```